# How to convert .srt subtitles to closed caption subtitles?

Tags: video, subtitles

I commonly use videos with .srt subtitles. Recently, somebody gave me a dvd player wich only accepts closed caption subtitles, so I can't play those videos.

Is there a way to convert .srt subtitles to closed captions subtitles? Is there any software to do this task?

Answer (score 1):

[VobSub](http://www.findfiles.com/search.src?file=VobSub_2.23.exe) should be able to help.

[Thorough directions.](http://www.recipester.org/Recipe:Convert_SRT_to_SUB_Subtitle_33953031)

Comment: no, it doesn't help

Comment: Link titled "thorough directions" currently looks like a page filled with ads.

Answer (score 1):

**[MovieCaptioner](http://www.synchrimedia.com)** can import SRT files and export SCC closed captions that are embedded into a QT movie. Requires QT Pro and the free ClosedCaptionImporter.compent plugin for QT from Apple.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between regular ol' subtitles and Closed Captioning.  Producing true closed captioning is extremely difficult.

The only software I've stumbled across that does closed captioning and doesn't cost a small fortune is QuickTime Pro.

Relevant links (some content is duplicated):

PDF link: http://www.ksd.k12.ky.us/trt/Closed_Captioning_with_QuickTimePro.pdf

http://amymangrich.com/wordpress/?p=28

http://www.wonderhowto.com/how-to-create-captioned-podcasts-with-quicktime-pro-245019/

Interesting side discussion on CCing:
http://forum.handbrake.fr/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=500&p=25841

Discussion on converting DVDs with CC to MP4 with subtitles:
http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/303281-DVD-s-with-closed-captions-to-MP4-s-with-subtitles

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.3playmedia.com/2011/08/26/3-steps-to-add-closed-captions-or-subtitles-with-quicktime/) is a tutorial to add closed captions and subtitles with QuickTime.

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon. Can you add more detail?